# Headless chrome print-to-pdf displays Chart.JS javascript canvas incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, charts, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to automatically print some webpages with a Chart.JS canvas element using headless chrome version 71 like so:
`start chrome --enable-logging --headless --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=10000 --print-to-pdf=C:\test.pdf example.html`

The result when I print from PDF manually in the Chrome browser looks exactly like it does on the webpage:
[image]

But in the PDF created from headless chrome the element is bizarrely changed:
[image]

Is there a way to get headless chrome to print a PDF precisely as the actual browser would have done?

Comment: same problem, if someone knows how to solve it, I assume that the problem is that Google chrome gives as the page loaded before the canvas has finished

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that web browser gives as the page loaded before the canvas has finished, To avoid this should generate some additional loads

at the end of the HTML code

add:

```
if ( location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf("HTTP") != 0) {
 var delay = 1000; // Delaying up load (in milliseconds).
  delay = new Date().getTime() + delay,
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 while (new Date().getTime() < delay ) {
  xhttp.open("GET", location.href, true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
}
```